# Prolog with c# visual studio 13

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, prolog

Prolog with c# using visual studio 13
but there is a problem with this exception :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

```
 using System;
 using SbsSW.SwiPlCs;

    namespace ConsoleApplication35
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(@"D:\Prolog\swipl", @"D:\Prolog\swipl\boot");
                if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
                {
                    String[] param = { "-q" }; 
                    PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                    PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(martin, inka))");
                    PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, gloria))");
                    PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, melanie))");
                    PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, ayala))");
                    using (var q = new PlQuery("father(P, C), atomic_list_concat([P,' is_father_of ',C], L)"))
                    {
                        foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                            Console.WriteLine(v["L"].ToString());

                        Console.WriteLine("all children from uwe:");
                        q.Variables["P"].Unify("uwe");
                        foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                            Console.WriteLine(v["C"].ToString());
                    }
                    PlEngine.PlCleanup();
                    Console.WriteLine("finshed!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to set the `PATH` environment variable, your code need to be changed as follows:

```
var curPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");  
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(@"PATH", @"D:\Prolog\swipl\boot;D:\Prolog\swipl;" + curPath );
```

Comment: Won't that overwrite the entire contents of the path variable?  Seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I would probably try to get the path variable, see if it contains my folder, if it doesn 't then I would add it to the end ( separated ) by semicolons.